# EXCEL: Show where two value ranges on different rows overlap

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to think there's a simple answer to this simple problem. How do I calculate column E - the 'overlap' - in this table?

I *have* tried to search for an answer on the web and here on S/O, but I can't think of a way of expressing the question in simple terms so I've not found anything similar.

So, the fruit represent events which begin in the 'Start' week and finish at the end of the 'End' week.

I want to make sure that the same fruit events are not happening in the same weeks. The overlap column should flag the first week that an overlap occurs.

[image]

Here's a link to the Excel sheet which might explain it a little better...
[Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xi725BMDv5rfSLB0jclJA2322wb1Au8O/view?usp=sharing)

I'm still pretty new to S/O so happy for suggestions on how I can improve the clarity of the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've been a member of the SO community for about a year. You should know by now that we expect to see code or a formula that you've tried since **show your original effort toward a solution** is written a couple dozen times every day in the [tag:excel] forum.

Comment: Being "a member of" and "actively using" are not the same thing. I've posted a small handful of questions.

Regarding 'code' or 'formula'... I don't know where to start with this. If you can help, please do, otherwise maybe leave it for others who might be more willing/able? Thanks.

Comment: ... apparently without ever researching or trying your own solution or bothering to read any of the many help pages like [ask] and [mcve]. A list of requirements is not a valid question.

Comment: I'd not read those pages, so thanks for drawing my attention to them. However, having now done so I think my question conforms, but if you're confused about any part of it or I've omitted any information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,C3):INDEX(A:A,D3))/(COUNTIFS(C:C,"<=" & ROW(INDEX(A:A,C3):INDEX(A:A,D3)),D:D,">=" & ROW(INDEX(A:A,C3):INDEX(A:A,D3)),B:B,B3)>1),1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is phenomenal - thank you. I will have to try to dissect what you've done here but it works perfectly.

Obviously my example has grossly simplified my real-world problem: this formula will replace about 250 columns of formulas in the workbook!